# Live ads for Facebook Audience Network without native Facebook app installed

Tags: android, facebook

On Android platform, we checked on Asus Zenfone 2 (ASUS_Z00AD),5.0 with Facebook Audience Network SDK version 4.16.1.

We are able to get Facebook test ads displayed without Facebook app being installed on device but we are not able to see live ads.
The error code is 1001.

As per https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/faq"
error code 1001 means :

1. The person testing has not logged into the native Facebook app on their mobile device
2. The person testing has enabled "Limit Ad Tracking" (iOS only) or has selected "Opt out of interest-based ads" (Android only) in their device settings.
3. We don't have ad inventory to show for that person

Note that if you can see test ads, your implementation works correctly and people will be able to see ads in your app once it's live.

Can we know what all things required to render Facebook audience network ad on Android? Is the Facebook app being installed on device is absolutely required?

Comment: Any news on this? Is having the facebook app installed a requirement?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [FAQ](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/support/faq#faq_645708608910328) and the [video](https://youtu.be/O64kyQTARLU?t=69), Facebook uses the IDFA (Identifier for Advertisers) on Apple devices or the Advertising ID on Android devices to match the device with its user's Facebook profile. To achieve that, it is a must to have the Facebook app installed and also the user needs to be logged on.